# Draw.io embed mode - customize edit link form

Tags: javascript, draw.io

Does Draw.io embed API provide any way to customize the edit link form? For example supplying a list of autocomplete values, dynamically fetched as the user types in the text field.

I have only found the [embed mode documentation](https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000042544-how-does-embed-mode-work-), which does not seem to mention any way of customizing the forms.